# Is Flexarome effective to relieve aching joints and tense muscles?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine, natural-remedies, herbalism

Flexarome is a blend of essential oils to relieve aching joints and tense muscles. It was created by [Dr. Jean Valnet](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Valnet), who is regarded as a founder of modern [aromatherapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromatherapy).

> Cold, humid weather and age are often the origin of joint pains, along with over exertion or the stress caused by frequent muscular contractions.
>
> In all these cases, FLEXAROME, composed of tincture of ginger, spirit of rosemary, essential oils of oregano, juniper, cypress and turpentine, gives you an immediate benefit (in 50 or 125 ml bottles).

from http://biorganic.perso.sfr.fr/valnetproduitsgb.htm

I would like to know specifically whether this product is effective to relieve aching joints and tense muscles or just some placebo. I couldn't find any articles on Google Scholar.

Comment: I've removed the aromatherapy blurb because it was confusing to the question and I've also removed any links to ecommerce sites. I've introduced an example claim so people can focus on the product in particular and not on aromatherapy in general.